# Selecting spheres one after the other

Tags: probability

I have 4 red, 2 black, 4 white and 5 yellow spheres.
I want to find the probability to draw a red then a white and finally a black sphere with this order.

Spheres number is 15.

Pred = 4/15
Pwhite = 4/14
Pblack = 2/13

The probability to draw the above sequence is (?) P = (4/15)(4/14)(2/13) = 0.0117.

If the above logic is correct,  is there a reference of a rule that allows me to multiply the probabilities in such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on *how* we draw the balls.

If we draw $3$ balls **with** replecement then the three events are independent and the probability factorizes:

$$
\mathbb{P}(R_1 \cap W_2 \cap B_3) = \mathbb{P}(R_1)\mathbb{P}(W_2)\mathbb{P}(B_3) = \frac{4}{15} \frac{4}{15}\frac{2}{15} = \frac{32}{15^3}
$$

If you draw them **without** replecement then the events are no longer independent and we may use the definition of conditional probability to get

$$
\mathbb{P}(R_1 \cap W_2 \cap B_3) = \mathbb{P}(B_3 \mid R_1 \cap W_2)\mathbb{P}(R_1 \cap W_2) = \mathbb{P}(B_3 \mid R_1 \cap W_2) \mathbb{P}(W_2 \mid R_1)\mathbb{P}(R_1) \\
= \frac{2}{13} \frac{4}{14}\frac{4}{15} = \frac{16}{1365}
$$